# remove the ajax request when redirecting

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have an Ajax form with 3 buttons for submission/cancel. The Post goes through fine and when it redirects to the next page it should go to, the correct action is called, but that new Action detects it as an Ajax request and instead of returning the full page, it tries returning a partial.

View contains:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("postingAction", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post" }, new { id = "myId" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 

        <buttons>
           ...
            <input type="submit" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" />
        </buttons>
        ...
}
```

Action that is called for the post:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "userType1, userType2")]
public ActionResult postingAction(myViewModel model)
{
   if (Request.Form["Cancel"] != null)
     return RedirectToAction("Action2", "DiffController");
   ...
}
```

Now when this RedirectToAction happens, this second action still detects that it was an Ajax call, how do I remove that it was an ajax call and make it a normal call?

Thanks,
David K.

Comment: Why not call direct action method for the view instead of `RedirectToAction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returing `JavaScriptResult`with desired url.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "userType1, userType2")]
public ActionResult postingAction(myViewModel model)
{
   if (Request.Form["Cancel"] != null)
     return JavaScript( "window.location = '" + Url.Action("Action2","DiffController") + "'" )

   ...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript%28v=vs.118%29.aspx